# Как поменять back face

Tags: blender

Как поменять backface местами, чтобы где синее был backface а где красная то там видимая область?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Такие варианты:

<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> -> **Flip Normals** - Вывернуть нормали

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> - Пересчитать нормали вовнутрь